# Jmeter with multiple keystores

Tags: ssl-certificate, jmeter, keystore, jks

I am trying to determine the best way to reference different keyStore files for my load testing needs.

I have different environments with different sets of certificates. One for development and one for staging. My goal is to use one test plan with parameters to tell Jmeter which environment to hit.

How do I tell Jmeter via Beanshell which keyStore to use? Current setup in the `system.properties` is the following:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:/apache-jmeter-2.9/bin/ssl/myKeyStore.jks
#The password to your keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=supersecret
```

Furthermore, if I pass in the following via command line:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore
```

does it override values assigned in the `system.properties` file?

Thanks for reading,
Jmeter-Fan

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved! It was just a simple assignment in your beanshell script and add some conditional logic to determine which environment to hit (tip: don't use single quotes for your parameters):

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","path/to/keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","supersecret");
```

Comment: issue not resolved. forgot to remove values in system.properties. the above lines of code are not the correct ones to use with beanshell within jmeter

Comment: Beware, keyStore is written in camel case: javax.net.ssl.keyStore

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the keystore configuration.

You just have to create a single p12 file with all your certificates, configure the system.properties et jmeter.properties, add the configuration to your test plan, and go !

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager;
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","foo.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","fooPW");
SSLManager.getInstance().reset();
```

This is in a code *sampler* like *Beanshell*, in the *ThreadGroup* where you want to switch to another keystore. Then, in this *ThreadGroup*, don't forget to place a *HTTP Request Defaults* configured like any SSL conf (https, Java implementation, server name and port).

I used it in a *Test Plan* where all tests are executed consecutively, if not, you should rework this solution.

Kinda tricky and ugly yes but it works.

Comment: FYI. While this worked for one alias, I could not get this to work for multiple aliases. I had to pass the keystore and password in on the commandline for that to work (Jmeter 3.1).